# Custom Easings in Aframe

Tags: aframe

Can I define custom easings for [Aframe animations](https://aframe.io/docs/core/animations.html)?

I'm hoping there's something available like [the cubic-bezier timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_cubic-bezier()_class_of_timing-functions) used in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[These are the easings](https://aframe.io/docs/core/animations.html#Easing) that AFRAME supports

For cubic easing you can do `ease-cubic`, `ease-in-cubic`, `ease-out-cubic`, `ease-in-out-cubic`.

AFRAME uses tween.js for value interpolation. If there's a function that it's not supported we would have to add it and expose it through aframe. It should not be difficult.